# Pandas.to_sql for one value

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I have a pandas `df` as follow :

```
id name value
1  A    5
2  Z    13
3  J    2
```

And the same MySQL database, which is a former version of the pandas dataframe, as follow :

```
id name value
1  A    5
2  Z    13
3  J
```

My target is to be able to add only the missing value ("2") to my sql database, from the dataframe.

I know that I should use `pd.to_sql`, but i don't know how to structure my request.

Comment: You have already inserted the value "2" into the dataframe and now you want to pull the dataframe as table in sql right? @Alex Dana

Comment: Yes, but only value 2

Answer (score 0):

IICU

You need to transfer the `df` data to `df_sql` If so use merge

In this case I would;

```
df2=df_sql.iloc[:,:2]#drop value
pd.merge(df2, df)#merge to transfer values from df
```